# Vba code: Filling the blank cells with zero dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fill my blank cells in a worksheet with zero. Currently I was doing it for C12:H35. Can someone please tell what's wrong in my code.Its not even giving any error.Also I need to do it dynamically .  So I was trying to do as

`Dim sht as Worksheet
  Set sht = This Workbook.Sheets("MySheet")
sht.Range(sht.cells(C12:3),sht.cells(12,Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Select`

None is working :(

This code is for non dynamic range,which again isn't working

```
  Sub FillEmptyCell
      Dim rng as Range
      Dim i as Long
      Dim cell as Range
  Set rng= Sheets("Mysheet").Range("C12:H35")

For each cell in rng
  If cell.value = " " Then cell.value= "0"
  End if 
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: First that there should '()' after FillEmptyCell.

Comment: In your non-dynamic version you are checking if the cell contains a space, cell.value = " ".  You most likely don't want that.  Try changing that part to If Trim(cell.value) = ""   As for your dynamic part I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Sorry those are the typing errors,I do have function bracket and there is not any space,yet its not running,the code isn't running the Then cell.value= "0".

Comment: When  i try your code it gave me an error 'End If without If block' so i removed End If it worked well for me. see my second answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code worked alright for me

```
Sub FillEmptyCell()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  sht.Activate
  'Range("C12:AL12").Select
  'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
  Set rng = Range(Range("C12"), Range("AD" & sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count))
  For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "" Then cell.Value = "0"
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ya it did .Thanks. Also the code I have mentioned above is for selecting the dynamic range,so instead of fixing the range as c12:h35 if I use the dynamic range above it doesn't work.

Comment: Dim sht as Worksheet Set sht = This Workbook.Sheets("MySheet") sht.Range(sht.cells(C12:3),sht.cells(12,Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Select

Comment: Please tell your expected start position of cell. I guess the end cell is dynamic value

Comment: The sheet starts filling from cell(12,3).And as the data us dynamic ,some values have data some are blank where I need to fill it with zero.It starts from 'C' column and goes till "AI"column,there can be dynamic rows.

Comment: So starting from C coloumn 12 row , and ends in AI coloumn but could be any Row. Am i right?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hope this should help you.If the code is working fine please mark it as answered.

Comment: Np... Welcome. Please mark the Question as Answered. So that it will be a ready to use answer

Comment: Am new to this ,how do we do that?

Comment: I guess you should have a Accept option for this answer.

Comment: Siva ,the code only goes one row down,it should be filling all rows down with zero.Also I guess because of the range ("c12:ad12").select,it highlights that entire 12th row from c to ad

Comment: It worked once fine,I have no clue wat is suddenly going wrong

Comment: in Your Excel sheet what was the available range. Manully select c12 to ad12 and then presSHIFT+CTRL+DOWN key. See what is the range available.Please note that even after Set rng line the sheet shows only 12 row as selected where as rng contains all the below rows as well.

Comment: I just don't know y it isn't working.It did for once .Then I closed and now it isn't :(

Comment: Okay Try debugging the code step by step you can figure out where exactly it is going wrong. Try to see it.

Comment: Let me know where exactly it is going wrong. I could see it working flawlessly for me

Comment: It highlights the range from c12:ad12 and fill zeroes in that row and a row below it.It doesn't goes to rows down.Not showing any error.Just that it's not spanning the entire rows

Comment: Try the edited code an see what is happening. Please check what is happening after the control comes to Set rng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

Comment: So now its highlighting the range c12: ad13 and filling them with zeroes,not going down the rows.

Comment: Do you have any rows which are below that row where you need to fill with zeros. That selection will only select those rows which were used. Like any one of cell in below rows should  have been used. Then only the selection will go to next rows.

Comment: Yeah I do,like a 13 rows below with 4-5 cells in each row filled,still ita not parsing. Even the syntax is all correct.I  can't figure out what's going wrong. also I told you na,it worked perfectly once,but now it isnt :(

Comment: Okay tell me whether the selection is happening when you try manually

Comment: Im not sure what went wrong with previous code. I have edited the answer and tried in other way. Give a try.

Comment: Np ... Try closing the sheet and running it againg as well :-)

Comment: Siva just one issue,the updated code fills the entire sheet with zero,even for rows where there is no data in any cell.Is it working the same way for u?

Comment: No. One reason could be due to that usedrange.rows.count. usedrange will consider all the cells that are used once.it's not necessary to have data. So for example a in last row is formated, or applied, but no value in cell also, usedrange.rows.count will give last row.

Comment: Hey Siva I have reposted your answer to see if someone can help.So you mean that I should remove the formatting? I can't do that.Cause I need data to be populated in the sheet in formatted way only.Is there no way out then?

Comment: Other way is instead of using used range, setting the range by using the lines I have commented.

Comment: Hm that also isn't working fine in my sheet Anyways,Thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I also have one more suggestion for you.

```
  Sub FillEmptyCell()
  Dim rng as Range
  Dim i as Long
  Dim cell as Range
  Set rng= Sheets("Mysheet").Range("C12:H35")
  Sheets("Mysheet").Activate
  rng.Select
  Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

  End Sub
```

Comment: It gives error as Select method of range class failed fir rng.Select

Comment: That may be beacuse the sheet is not activated. Try the edited code

Comment: I tested it, Worked perfectly for me

Comment: Why, why, _why_ use activate/select/selection? Pointless and spoils an otherwise good answer

Comment: @chris neilsen Im sorry if that is wrong. I guess the sheet should be active before the code go ahead and select when there are multiple sheets and if the control is in not in the sheet  where i need to perform selection. I guess your suggestion is directly use rng.Replace... Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but your if statement was off, I also changed the quotation marks to not have a space in them. When that's the case, VBA looks for a space in a cell, not an empty cell.

```
Sub FillEmptyCell()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range

    Range("C1").Select
    colRef = ActiveCell.Column
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count & colRef).End(xlUp).Row
    Do Until ActiveCell.Column = 31
        colRef = ActiveCell.Column
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count & colRef).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 1 To lastrow
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
                ActiveCell.Value = "0"
                ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
            End If
        Next
        ActiveCell.Offset(-lastrow, 1).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of dynamic range? I didn't understand in your question

Comment: The range can vary depending upon the data. Currently am just doing for C12:H35.but there can be any number of rows spanning the columns from C to AD.so for that I need to modify my code

Comment: And you want all blank cells in that range to say 0? Let me have a look

Comment: I think with the amount of variation inn the ranges, your only option would to be to loop through all cells in each column and fill them out one column at a time. It might take a while to run, but I'll have a go for you anyway.

Comment: See my edited answer, should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Josh what is the type of lastrow and colRef and x? I put it as long,range and int respectively .Am I correct?

Comment: I find `lastrow as long` `colRef as long` and `x as integer` works nicely

Answer (score 0):

Select a range in sheet and try running this code

```
Sub FillBlanksWithZero()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
End Sub
```

I hope this will helps you :)